# ¿Cómo usar spring cloud bus?

Tags: java, spring-boot

¿Cómo funciona `cloud-bus`? ¿Se usa `templates`?

¿Cuál es la clase principal de este `framework`? ¿Es `SimpMessagingTemplate`?

Las dependencias del `cloud-bus` son:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-redis</artifactId>
    <!-- or -amqp (rabbitmq) or -kafka -->
  </dependency>
<!-- ... -->
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Creo que la primera fuente de consulta debería ser la documentación [aqui](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-bus/1.3.0.RELEASE/). No parece que exista un problema real, por lo que propongo la pregunta para cierre, en tanto se clarifica la pregunta.